# Cocoa Move Mouse

Tags: cocoa

I'm writing a Mac OS X application on Snow Leopard.  I have a step method which is fired at a regular interval by a NSTimer.  In this method I would like to move the mouse to the center of the screen, with no buttons being pressed or released.  Here's what I have:

```
-(void) step: (NSTimer *) timer
{
 NSRect bounds = [self bounds];

 CGPoint point = CGPointMake(bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width / 2.0f, bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height / 2.0f);

 CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseDragged, point, 0);
}
```

This doesn't do anything.  Can somebody tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like CGWarpMouseCursorPosition is precisely what you're after (it moves the pointer without generating events - see the [Quartz Display Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html) for more info).